# How to get remote client's IP address in an express based Node JS app running on App-Engine

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, express, gcloud, gcloud-node

While trying to get IP, all standard headers values contain incorrect value.

```
req.ip: ::ffff:172.17.0.5
req.headers['x-forwarded-for']: 169.254.160.2
req.socket.remoteAddress: ::ffff:172.17.0.5
```

All of these result in wrong ip.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Solutions:

1. Either use `let ip = req.headers['x-appengine-user-ip']` or
2. Use [Express's](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/behind-proxies.html) trust proxy settings by using `app.set('trust proxy', true);`

Explanation: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/runtime#https_and_forwarding_proxies

> App Engine terminates the HTTPS connection at the load balancer and forwards the request to your application. 
>   The user's IP address is available in the standard `X-Forwarded-For` header as well as the `X-Appengine-User-Ip` header. Applications that require this information should configure their web framework to trust the proxy.

Complete list of header values for each request:

```
{
    "host": "<APP_ID>.appspot.com",
    "x-real-ip": "169.254.160.2",
    "x-forwarded-for": "169.254.160.2",
    "x-google-real-ip": "169.254.160.2",
    "x-appengine-user-ip": "2620:0:1002:100a:2c4b:4f6b:7851:a9d9",
    "x-appengine-api-ticket": "aad4544d4e04a1a0",
    "x-appengine-user-email": "",
    "x-appengine-auth-domain": "gmail.com",
    "x-appengine-user-id": "",
    "x-appengine-user-nickname": "",
    "x-appengine-user-organization": "",
    "x-appengine-user-is-admin": "0",
    "x-appengine-request-id-hash": "A104B85B",
    "x-appengine-request-log-id": "5748c500ff00ff09eec9a104b85b0001737e736d6172742d737061726b2d39333632320001323031363035323774313530323538000100",
    "x-appengine-https": "on",
    "x-appengine-datacenter": "us6",
    "x-appengine-default-version-hostname": "smart-spark-93622.appspot.com",
    "cache-control": "max-age=0",
    "accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8",
    "upgrade-insecure-requests": "1",
    "save-data": "on",
    "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.63 Safari/537.36",
    "accept-language": "en-US,en;q=0.8",
    "x-appengine-country": "US",
    "x-appengine-region": "ca",
    "x-appengine-city": "san francisco",
    "x-appengine-citylatlong": "37.774929,-122.419416",
    "x-cloud-trace-context": "4a77265a7fa3e11be8cccebce59f7702/9314487514850703289;o=5"
}
```

As one can see, `x-forwarded-for` is being set as `x-google-real-ip`. So user's ip is now available in `x-appengine-user-ip`.