# Validating cron requests on client IP

Tags: google-app-engine

According to the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/scheduling-jobs-with-cron-yaml):

> You might want to validate that requests to your cron URLs are coming
>   from App Engine and not from another source. You can do so by
>   validating an HTTP header and the source IP address for the request:

...

> Google App Engine issues cron requests from the IP address 10.0.0.1.

If I validate in my Express handler function on `req.ip` it reports `::ffff:172.17.0.1`. Am I missing something or are the docs incorrect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like `::ffff:172.17.0.1` was the result of a bug in the app engine / google cloud. Now requests are correctly reporting the documented `10.0.0.1`.

Answer (score 0):

> I came across this question when I faced a similar problem. I think it
>   might me helpful to others.

For me the issue was App-Engine Proxy. Since, the App-Engine is running behind a proxy, I needed to enable `trust proxy` in my express app.

```
app.enable('trust proxy')
```

[See this thread for more details.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37493134/how-to-get-remote-clients-ip-address-in-an-express-based-node-js-app-running-on)